# What kind of pine is this?

Tags: identification, trees, seeds, pines

I collected seeds of a local pine tree, and the seeds were different from typical pine seeds I've seen before. It has a little needle sticking from the end of it. The tail is stiffer and doesn't break as easily. The seed as a whole is about 2 inches.

[image]

This tree was growing in San Diego.
Here's a picture of it's leaves.

[image]

The tree was a mature tree. Not tall and conical, but rather had medium height (20-30 feet) and a dome shaped canopy.

Update:
As @blacksmith37 noted in the accepted answer below, this wasn't actually a pine. It was some sort of mesquite tree. These seeds did travel quite a bit.

Comment: Good question & good illustrations; if could include an overall illustration,  close illustrations of a cone & of the bark, dimensions of a cone, thickness of the seed, needle length, trunk diameter, bark features, and elevation where the tree was growing, could also be helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seed in the photo is some kind of maple ; they move well with wind so it may have come some distance.

Comment: You were right. When I went back to the location I found a tree near by with these seeds. It wasn't a maple but it was some sort of mesquite tree.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly for the San Diego area it will need to be a species adapted to very dry, hot conditions which will eliminate a lot of the temperate species of the north. The [San Diego Zoo](https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/plants/conifers) site mentions three Pinus species, *P. coulteri*, *P. halepensis* and *P. torreyana*. The descriptions provided in sites like wikipedia don't provide sufficient detail to distinguish these by seed shape and size so we need recourse to authorities like https://www.conifers.org/pi/Pinus_torreyana.php where there is a lot more detail on the samara morphology. Note that the seed body and wing sizes are listed separately, putting at least *P. halepensis* in as a candidate since the seed body is shorter than the wing portion approaching the two inches overall you have noted.